# populated attrib in form element doesn't get its value passed

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm creating a form text field, but would like to set an additional attribute called `additional` so the html markup looks like this.

```
<dd id="email-element">
   <input type="text" value="" id="email" name="email" additional="">
</dd>
```

I'm able to set the attribute using `setAttrib` like so.

```
$email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
$email->setAttrib('additional', '');
$this->addElement($email);
```

I'm then setting the value of `additional` on the client side via ajax. But when the form is submitted, `additional` appears empty. When I var_dump the form, I can see it as an attribute on this form field, but it's empty. Also when I var_dump the request, it's not on it (which is understandable since it's an attribute, and not the field value itself). Is there a way to read attributes that were changed on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has no way of reading form attributes that were modified in the browser, but you can read it on the client side and send it back to PHP.  The only data submitted are the element values themselves.

If you need the attribute in PHP, add a hidden input called `additional` (or whatever you like), and during the form's `onsubmit` event, you can read the value of the attribute, and populate the hidden element and then submit the form.  Note that if the client has Javascript disabled, the value will not come through, but that method can be used to read it and send it to the server.

Hope that helps.